# Error gyp when install protractor

Tags: npm, protractor, node-gyp, gyp

When i try install

```
npm i protractor
```

I have error. I have install 
msvs_version 2015 
GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(514,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform too lset (v140) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected. [D:\Projects\angularjs\no de_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\angularjs\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you satisfied all the steps listed here https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#prerequisites

Afterwards if it still doesn't work try

```
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015
or the npm example
npm install --msvs_version=2015
```